# How to set up Idea under MacOs

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I downloaded Idea EAP 2017.3 Ultimate for Mac OS, with a bundled jre.

Once I cloned my gradle project, I tried to sync but it was complaining that there was no project SDK.

I tried to add the bundled jre under `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home` but it always complained it wasnt a valid JDK home.

So I downloaded the jre 9 and installed.

Added that as Project SDK, now I get this:

```
The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch: 
Java home is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/loredanasoetta/.gradle/daemon,pid=421,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IT,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=d56a6606-9df7-4dbb-b269-96531b5ba6f9,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/loredanasoetta/.gradle/daemon,pid=481,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IT,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
```

1) Why the bundled jre doesn't get accepted?

2) I saw some people solved by explicitly declaring the jdk path in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

`org.gradle.java.home=/Library...`

but this is crap because it'd be pushed on the repo and it's valid only for me

Which is the right way to do have Idea on Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

Credits to Serge Baranov

1. The bundles runtime that is not a complete JDK, you need to have normal JDK installed for development, see [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-184243).
2. Configure JDK used to run Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA:

[image]